# (windows) reset or change username & password for a login to another computer (samba/linux) on the LAN

Tags: networking, password, user-accounts

When you open up the 'Network' window on windows, and you see computers and or network shares for the workgroup, well, I accidentally input the wrong username / password for the computer it is connecting to, and I can't seem to change the username \ password and or reset it.

On the LAN, I have a linux box using samba, all permissions are correct, since the the vista box *can* log in just fine and access whatever, however, on the vista box, I checked 'always remember' the username/password, and now I can't change that to another account I need to change it to.

I have been searching for hours, and can't seem to find the answer.

I did try to disable the account on the linux side, and that did work, however, then, it says 'access denied', with no way to enter a new username / password!

Anyone have a clue on how to fix this ?

***edit:
Finally found the answer.

In the cmd prompt, (admin rights), do **control userpasswords2**  then hit **Advanced tab** and finally, the **Manage Passwords** button.

Answer (score 1):

In the command prompt, do control userpasswords2, then Advanced, and then Manage Passwords